# Ajax & Php post issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Hello i was looking to write a script for sending information to PHP via ajax but i think i had some errors hence i would like some help.

#### AJAX

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".infitem").offset({ top: 0, left: 0 });

    $(".item").hover(function(){
        var op = $(this);

        var pos = $(op).offset();
        var height = $(op).height();
        var width = $(op).width();

        $(".infname").html(op.attr("iname"));
        $(".infdesc").html("Level: "+op.attr("ilevel")+((op.attr("iu1") != "") ? "<br />#"+op.attr("iu1") : ""));

        if(op.attr("ilevel") != "")
            $(".infitem").show();

        $(".infitem").css({ "left": pos.left + (width / 2) - ($(".infdesc").width() / 2) + "px", "top": pos.top + height + "px" });

    },function(){
        $(".infitem").hide();
    });

    $(".item").click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("id") == "notselected"){
            $(this).appendTo("#selitems");
            $(this).attr("id", "selected");
        }else if($(this).attr("id") == "selected"){
            $(this).appendTo("#allitems");
            $(this).attr("id", "notselected");
        }else if($(this).attr("id") == "gamenotselected"){
            $(this).appendTo("#selitems");
            $(this).attr("id", "gameselected");
        }else if($(this).attr("id") == "gameselected"){
            $(this).appendTo("#allgames");
            $(this).attr("id", "gamenotselected");
        }
    });

    $("#rafBut").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(this).attr("value", "Please wait...");

        var itms = new Array();
        var gmes = new Array();
        var ia = 0;
        var ga = 0;

        $(".item").each(function(i){
            if($(this).attr("id") == "selected"){
                itms[ia] = $(this).attr("iid")+":"+$(this).attr("iqual")+":"+$(this).attr("ilevel")+":"+$(this).attr("iu1");
                ia++;
            }
            if($(this).attr("id") == "gameselected"){
                gmes[ga] = $(this).attr("iid");
                ga++;
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/raffle.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "postraffle": "true",
                "title": $("#rtitle").val(),
                "message": $("#mess").val(),
                "maxentry": $("#maxentry").val(),
                "duration": $("#durr").val(),
                "filter": $("#reffil").val(),
                "split": $("input[name=split]:checked").val(),
                "pub": $("input[name=rafflepub]:checked").val(),
                "stype": $("input[name=stype]:checked").val(),
                "invo": $("input[name=invo]:checked").val(),
                "items[]": itms,
                "games[]": gmes,
                },
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status == "fail")
                {
                    alert(data.message);
                    $("#rafBut").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#rafBut").attr("value", "Raffle it!");
                }

                else if(data.status == "ok")
                {
                window.location.href = "http://localhost/raffle.php";
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

^ This is the ajax part of the script
in the above script the information would be sent via POST and it would be in json format

#### raffle.php

```
 <?php
$data =$_POST['rafBut'];
echo $data;
?>
```

Hence i just want the information to be shown in JSON format so i can easily encorprate with php.
and is there any other way to do this (Just using php without ajax)
here is an live example of this - http://admin.tftrg.com/Prototype/raffle.html
but it doesnt seem to work
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see a "rafBut" key in the data you are sending.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$json = array();
$json["data"] = array("status" => $_POST['rafBut']);
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Also change `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "post"`

Comment: Doesn't work. i have tried it and uploaded it here as u said view to the source take a look of that admin.tftrg.com/Prototype/raffle.html

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `localhost` in `url: "http://localhost/raffle.php"` to `admin.tftrg.com` or just remove it (so you get `url: "/raffle.php"`).

**raffle.php**

```
<?php
// $_POST['rafBut'] - what is it? It is not passed via AJAX

// response fields
$data = array(
    'status' => 'fail',
    'message' => 'Failed to save data',
);

/* some operations with $_POST data */

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. i have tried it and uploaded it here as u said view to the source take a look of that http://admin.tftrg.com/Prototype/raffle.html

Comment: It's because you change value of "`dataType`" on prototype to wrong value "`php`". The value should be "`json`". [see available values of dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for your responce but now the pop up show FAILED TO SAVE DATA http://admin.tftrg.com/Prototype/raffle.html < you can see it there

Comment: You should write some logic in your `raffle.php`. At now script print one of expected responses (fail or ok). Data which send to script are not processed

Comment: So if you want to validate data or to save it, you need to implement this logic in `raffle.php`

Comment: how do i echo all of the transmitted information thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use debug tools such as Firebug on Firefox, you will see that your call is correctly sent. The only thing to change seems to be the beginning of your URLs, replacing localhost by your real context such as http://admin.tftrg.com

Comment: Doesn't work. i have tried it and uploaded it here as u said view to the source take a look of that admin.tftrg.com/Prototype/raffle.html